# Allow editing of main documentation name or title

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Please have a look at the [Prolog documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/prolog/topics): The tabs read "**prolog**" [sic], "dashboard", and "topics".

For comparison, in the [C documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics), the tabs read "**C language**", "dashboard" and "topics".

There does not appear to be a way to edit the main name of the documentation from prolog to Prolog language. Can a way be added so these are editable?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: is this something general? I.e. Prolog language, C++ language, etc. Or a per-language decision? Should we go for a "style-guide" there?

Comment: The downvote is also a nice touch for a request to enhance consistency of how documentation about programming languages is presented to users. How about changing "C language" to "c" for consistency?

Comment: It's a feature request. Those can come with an "I disagree" downvote. Don't sweat it too much. The request is fine, and it would be a nice moment to settle on whatever structure, if possible/necessary. I fact, I'd rather opt for the "C" edit over the "Prolog language" edit.

Comment: OK, I see. In my view, at the very least, the tab should read "Prolog" instead of "prolog". Both "Prolog" or "Prolog language" would be fine in my view.

Comment: The same for "[common-lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/common-lisp/topics)". It should at least read "[Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp)" (or perhaps "Common Lisp Language").

Comment: The tab actually reads “C Language”, so for consistency it should be “Prolog Language”.

Comment: The same should be done to other languages, say Actionscript 3, or Common Lisp, or F#, it's just this thing is done manually, and the respective communities didn't request their documentation pages to be renamed in such way.

Comment: @mat I've updated this to make it more general because it seems like this applies to more docs than just prolog.

Comment: Related support question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329208/how-to-change-the-title-of-a-tag-in-the-documentation-project

Comment: This [tag:feature-request] also came up before in Docs-beta: http://i.stack.imgur.com/l5G7L.png, it's called the tag's Friendly Name

Comment: I second the feature-request. Here's another example: [entity-framework-core](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework-core)