# Documentation Update, October 20th

Tags: discussion, documentation

It's time for another Documentation Update!  This is post six in the series; here's the [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335529/80572).

### Shipped

#### Review Audits and Bans

The audits themselves rolled out a bit ago, but bans are now live as well.

[image: Failing an audit]

Audits are triggered by suspicious review behavior, and bans are handed out for repeatedly failing audits.  Bans start at 48 hours, and grow from there.

Audits themselves are based on the [suggested edit review queue's behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165489/130213) - we aren't re-using old changes, instead we're making new bad ones.

#### Rollback Reasons

When proposing a rollback, you now need to specify *why*.  These reasons are shown in review.

[image: Rollback reason popup]

In the future (we don't have enough data yet) rollback reasons will be used to determine if a user's changes need additional reviews, or if they should be banned from editing for a time.

#### Rollback From Review

Completed proposed change reviews now show a rollback option, if you can rollback that change.

[image: Rollback option]

#### User Profile Changes

On the Documentation tab on your profile, the behavior of the Contributions and Proposed Changes subtabs have changed.

Contributions now lists all the topics and examples you are a major or minor contributor to  (see the [reputation announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334551/80572) for how contributor status is determined).

Proposed Changes now lists *all* the changes you have ever proposed, including those that have been accepted or rejected.

[image: Updated tabs]

### Planned Changes

#### Topic Introduction

We're implementing the (often mentioned in prior) per-Topic Focus/Introduction optional section.  We decided it was more important to get review audits and bans out, but this is coming soon.

#### Improvement Request Changes

[Changes announced in the last update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335529/80572) are still being worked on.

#### Discussion

We've wrapped up the first round of tests on a Discussion feature (thanks to those who participated).  We're now putting together the next iteration, and intend to start tests on that version in the near future.

Here are some updated mockups:

[image: Discussion mockups]

#### Introduction/Overview/Hello World Topic Changes

We're making a few changes to a tag's initial topic, at various times called the Hello World, Overview, or Introduction topic.

- We're standardizing it in the UI as Introduction
- The title will now be of the form `Getting started with {tag friendly name}`

  - Sufficiently high reputation users (and moderators) can change a tag's friendly name by editing its tag wiki
- The introduction topic will always be the first topic on page one of all topics list
- The `All Versions` span on the topic and topic list will be replaced with a new span that indicates the introduction topic is special

We're hoping these changes will make the special nature of the introduction topic clearer to users.

Comment: Could we also have a "irrelevant cosmetic change" for the rollback reasons? Because there's some rep-farming going on with that.

Comment: Getting SO SICK of these animated gif memes in... wait, these are relevant. Nice.

Comment: in other words users with less than 500 rep are still being allowed into the review queue. Are we going to do the same for the rest of the review queues? or is there a reason this one is different.

Comment: I don't understand how these people are reviewing these topics they appear to have no interest/background in when I can't bring myself to do the same even for examples that look like good examples. I have no way of knowing whether or not the example is accurate/correct and not a duplicate from the review queue. I can see approving/rejecting minor contributions (grammar/spelling) but adding new topics/examples? they're all in the same bucket.

Comment: @S.L.Barth What sorts of cosmetic changes do you consider a problem? I don't see why I would reject a change that corrects lower vs. upper case, for example, if it makes the documentation more polished. On the other hand, I've also reviewed changes where a double quote was replaced with a single quote where it made no difference in the language. Regarding rep-farming in general, isn't it a net good if people to feel motivated to nitpick at things for the +2 reward? It's not as if these non-substantive contributors will receive rep if the content gets upvoted anyways.

Comment: @mnoronha IMO, changes that merely Capitalize the First Letters of Verbs, Adjectives and Nouns add no value. One person finds it more pleasing to the eye, another does not and may revert it. I feel we should focus on improving the content. Let's not make cosmetic changes unless there is an agreement to abide by a specific style.

Comment: Bans are live! Rejoice!

Comment: Is there a plan to be able to suggest deletion of "Zombie Tags" in documentation that were created, but should not have been created?  Ones like this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android-layout/917/introduction-to-android-layout#t=201610202055203944027

Comment: @S.L.Barth Sure, but the better solution IMO would be to create some sort of style guide. When documentation comes out of beta, we can expect a lot more traffic. With this the volume of edit requests to change cosmetics is going to increase a lot (unless the rep threshold for editing was raised). I think it's silly to accept/reject on personal preference or just reject all stylistic changes period. Having a standardized style would help streamline things a lot and make documentation better.

Comment: So, exactly how much rep. do you need to change a tag's friendly name?

Comment: Re: *"Sufficiently high reputation users (and moderators) can change a tag's friendly name by editing its tag wiki"*. Related: *[Allow anyone to edit the tag’s friendly name](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335569)*

Comment: And: *[Allow editing of main documentation name or title](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329761)*

Comment: Thanks for making the site, is comments on examples is in the feature pipeline?

Comment: @KevinMontrose -- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338274/561731

Comment: Or even @Shog9 ^

Answer (score 56):

Audits? Finally. It is a little late though, unfortunately.

These bans should have been ready *prior* to the review queue being opened for Documentation *Beta*, *especially* considering the queue was basically open to anyone with an account here.

Robo reviewing wreaked havoc on the content quality of Documentation, and many users spent a lot of time fixing the results, myself included. Unfortunately, the minor change of audits may not be enough to stop robo reviewing in Documentation. It is the only queue aside from Late Answers with no items to review at the moment.

It is very hard to review what is going on in the Documentation review queue. While there may be some (and by some I mean a sliver) of oversight available now, it is still nearly impossible to monitor changes without excessive manual inspection.

<strike>Moreover, there is not even a link for recent reviews to determine to what extent beyond terrible recent robo reviewing really is.</strike> This was incorrect. While the link may not exist, as Kevin B points out, the availability of this list is still present. Here is a direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history (which is also available by clicking on history while reviewing an item in the Documentation queue). Perhaps this link (recent reviews) could be included in the review queues page?

There needs to be a higher barrier (3000 reputation?) to reviewing Documentation while it is still in Beta and fixing content takes significant amount of time to both repair and observe.

Comment: _"There needs to be a higher barrier (3000 reputation?) to reviewing Documentation"_ As long as those of us with low rep can still access, though not vote on, the reviews from the tag dashboards, I 100% agree. I've done a couple rollbacks of bad approvals myself, in the tag I follow on documentation. Is easier to have a heads up if you see the review in progress beforehand.

Comment: @Kendra - I meant the review queue with that statement, sorry if there was any confusion. I do not think the dashboard experience should change based on reputation.

Comment: I knew what you meant, I was more pointing it out in case others felt the dashboard should be changed. I'm sure someone will say, "Well, why do they need to be able to see the reviews in the dashboard if they can't review them?" even though they are useful to see ahead of time, if you get the warning.

Comment: @KevinB - Ugh. Where were you to tell me this in all the other conversations we have had lol

Comment: "There needs to be a higher barrier (3000 reputation?) to reviewing Documentation" **NO!** Documentation is supposed to be wiki-like - we can't keep it that way if we raise the reputation bar for reviewing to 1000 or more.

Comment: You left out the *Beta* context in that quote, the suggestion is just temporarily. Also, the wiki like nature is with regards to contributing by making edits or creating content, and decidedly not about a review queue.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330049/248058 (observation)

Comment: I'd just like to suggest that the review barrier could also take tag badges, and possibly progress towards tag badges, into account, where tag badges either are allowed to override rep requirements, or lower them.  If reviewing an item in, say, the Java changes queue, I'd trust someone with a bronze badge for Java, but only 1500 reputation, more than I'd trust someone with 3000 rep and zero tag score for Java.  Perhaps a tag badge can override rep requirements for that tag entirely, and a user's tag score decreases their review rep requirement for that tag?

Comment: Obviously the whole contents of Documentation needs to be nuked once the Beta stuff settles. Most topics are currently of such horrible quality that they are directly harmful reading. When this whole project was rolled out as a suggestion on meta, the most valid argument was: "why do we need wikipedia 2 but with worse quality?". And that is where Documentation has landed - it is just like wikipedia, but incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

PLEASE DESIST FROM USING ANIMATION.

**What's up Doc?**

What I'd really like is an overview of what Documentation currently is. The initial setup is unrecognisably changed.  Pages-long updates really do not help clearing the picture.

Overly negative? A sizeable number of my updates perished on bugs. Press submit, unclear message, work gone. My motivation plummeted on foggy improvements building a monster seemingly mostly guarding "rep value".

My impression is that first the crowd rushed in, mods retroactively played the system and now confusion reigns. And that the reward system got fatally broken in the process.
At least for me.
And in all that, what is actually happening to Doc? Is it any good? Is it actually still alive?

As it stands now I have no trust in Doc nor am I in any way inclined to contribute. This state is miles from my starting point.

Any debunking of the above is greatly appreciated - but it better be GOOD.

Comment: The above is a question. In an answer slot. Posted as reaction to an update that is in a question slot. Kind of backwards. But it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have no idea what you wanted to say or ask.

Comment: @anatolyg, maybe that is part of the problem. But it is nice to see that confusion reigns all over.

Comment: Just being curious though, what is your opinion on Doc, @anatolyg?

Comment: Wow, the horde just passed. Predicted.

Comment: I also have a bit of concerns regarding the documentation procject as I'm unsure if the documentation should cover every nuance of some topic and thus build up to some kind of reference or as small code samples are preferred just replace Githubs gist-system. Some of the documentations seem really messy, some overly long, some repeat just information already available in an other topic (i.e. look at rest-http (where I contributed to myself) which basically summarizes/extends general REST and HTTP documentation stuff.