# Increase the size of the proposed change description box

Tags: discussion, documentation, comments

I was going through the php docs and had some updates/fixes on several sub-topics. Apparently, the changes are all bundled into a single change request. Understandable, but I don't know if it's desirable.

---

I wanted to justify my changes for each topic, but the comment box is too small. Now I have stopped reviewing the documentation because I can't justify my changes anymore. For me this is very counter productive.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the sort of comments you hoped to include? For what it's worth, we are working on a [discussion feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336627/documentation-update-october-20th) that ought to allow users to talk about a topic in a more freeform way. It might be possible to write up your changes there and link to that discussion in the change description. But I really don't know what sort of comments you are hoping to make.

Comment: @JonEricson, per chapter I had 1 or 2 small sentences describing my rationale for changing. For example, one of the code samples had defaults for some parameters which I removed. I added a comment that I think it is bad design to have those defaults and why I removed them. Ultimately I think that every change should be reviewed, and it is beneficial to the reviewer and reviewee to give some context to a change.