# Can we remove the "Documentation Update, October 20th" from the "Featured on Meta" sidebar?

Tags: discussion, meta

It is more than a month old and there have been progress with bugs and updates since then on the [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) tag.

[image]

Comment: @Gothdo -- it is not only featured on meta - it is also featured on the main site!

Comment: Is a meta question really needed for this? Couldn't a comment have been posted on the question first to see if that took care of it? (I agree that no longer needs to be featured, but I feel like this was a little much to start with to try to accomplish that.)

Comment: @Kendra really the `featured` tag just needs to be removed. This is the same vain as a tag removal question.

Comment: @Neal But that question is on Meta.

Comment: Yes, I get that. And why wouldn't a comment on the featured post handle that? The OP of the post _can_ remove that tag. A tag removal for _one question_ feels a bit overkill, even if it is a tag only mods can edit out. Now if a comment had been made a couple weeks ago and hadn't been handled, this would feel completely appropriate.

Comment: haha that is very meta @Gothdo ;-P

Comment: @Kendra I would even bring it up in chat (for meta) but it seems I have some issues loading the chat javascript locally.... :-( for some reason the chat cdn'd js is blocked by my office for malware (trying to figure that out now)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should've been removed already - there's a scheduled task that's supposed to strip the tag after 30 days.

...Unfortunately, it only runs weekly, and we weren't *quite* at 30 days the last time it ran.

I just edited it out.

Comment: So when's the next Documentation Update?

Comment: When there's something non-trivial to report.