# Documentation: grammar mistake "Getting started with..."?

Tags: discussion, documentation, grammatical-correction

I noticed that in the Stack Overflow documentation the *"Getting started with [name]"* topic can lead to (unwanted?) grammar mistakes. For example, the documentation for *"Python Language"* becomes *"Getting started with Python Language"*.

Grammatically correct would be either *"Getting started with the Python Language"* (as Python is now used as an adjective of the noun Language, the article of the noun therefore stays) or *"Getting started with Python"*.

As far as I can see this applies for almost all languages. This could thus be corrected automatically?

Comment: Replacing the word "with" with a spacer of some sort would work around this problem Something like this, for instance: "Python Language – Getting Started".

Comment: Or _"Getting Started With : Python Language"_. But does it really matter - I think it is totally clear what is meant.

Comment: Well, this is "by design" as witnessed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336627/documentation-update-october-20th. Sufficiently high-rep users can change the [name] portion, but making it work with "Getting started with" might make it look funny elsewhere (e.g., it would show up in the list of tags as "the Python Language" and people would complain about the lack of initial capital). I believe the way it is now is good enough.

Comment: Edit it here: http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/16 It's the first field.

Comment: Couldn't something like the following be implemented? `"Getting started with " + (name.endsWith(" Language") ? "the " + name : name)`

Comment: Why is it "Python Language", not just "Python"? I mean, when we can't even get _that_ right...

Comment: @Hat: Nice idea, but it would fall down with anything like, for example, "Getting started with Machine Language"...

Comment: @psmears That's a good point. Though currently the only tag in Documentation ending with "Language" that wouldn't work is "Assembly Language". Every other tag is a specific (programming) language. As BoundaryImposition has asked, why the need for the redundant "Language" in the first place? There are numerous examples of tags in Documentation, which are in fact tags for languages, but where the tag doesn't end with "Language", e.g. JavaScript, PHP, Go, SQL, HTML, CSS, and cobol (which is inexplicably lowercase).

Comment: No native English speaker would say "Getting started with Python Language", but I can assure you that in that example "Python" is still a noun; it is _not_ an adjective. In that example "Python Language" is a [_compound noun_](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=compound+noun&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gwn9WIeXMJT98wfCrZzAAw).

Comment: I think Go can do with the word Language...

Comment: @Hat and others. It seems that quite some people feel that either "Language" should be omitted in the topic of the documentation, or either in the "Getting started with...". However, I have no idea how to proceed from here?